# Swiping to a element not present in dom in appium ios

Tags: appium

I have an app where a particular parent that has n elements lets say 10 elements (tiles) and only 5 are present in the dom and visible in the current screen. The next 5 would appear in dom/screen on swiping up. How do I swipe to a particular element say 7th element?

I'm not able to get find the element by id/name as the element is not in dom so I'm not able to use swipe until visibility of an element. also, the number of such elements varies based on how the backend system is configured so I cannot make a fixed number of swipes. Also since I do not know the last element in the parent I'm at risk of running into an infinite loop if the particular element is not present in the app (due to a bug).

Please help on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods to scroll down until expected element. To avoid the infinite loop you can keep count of while loop.

```
public void scrollDown()
{
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction((AppiumDriver)driver);
    action.press(new PointOption().point(300, 701)).waitAction(newWaitOptions().waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(2))).moveTo(new PointOption().point(300, 441)).release();
    action.perform();
}


public void scrollTillElement(By element)
{
    int countofLoop = 0;
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(element);

    while (elements.size()==0)
    {
        countofLoop++;
        scrollDown();
        elements = driver.findElements(element);
        if(countofLoop==20)
         {
            break;
         }
    }
}
```